# How to process a simple loop in Perl's WWW::Mechanize?

Tags: perl, parsing, dom, mechanize

Especially interesting for me as a PHP/Perl-beginner is this site in Switzerland:
[see this link:http://www.edi.admin.ch/esv/00475/00698/index.html?lang=de&webgrab_path=http://esv2000.edi.admin.ch/d/entry.asp?Id=1308](http://www.edi.admin.ch/esv/00475/00698/index.html?lang=de&webgrab_path=http://esv2000.edi.admin.ch/d/entry.asp?Id=1308)
 
Which has a dataset of 2700 foundations. All the data are free to use  with no limitations copyrights on it.

**what we have so far:**  Well the harvesting task should be no problem if i take  WWW::Mechanize - particularly for doing the form based search and selecting the individual entries. Hmm - i guess that the algorithm would be basically 2 nested loops: the outer loop runs the form based search, the inner loop processes the search results.

The outer loop would use the select() and the submit_form() functions on the second search form on the page. Can we use DOM processing here. Well - how can we get the get the selection values.

The inner loop through the results would use the follow link function to get to the actual entries using the following call.

```
$mech->follow_link(url_regex => qr/webgrab_path=http:\/\/evs2000.*\?
Id=\d+$/, n => $result_nbr);
```

This would forward our **mechanic browser** to the entry page. Basically the URL query looks for links that have the webgrap_path to Id pattern, which is unique for each database entry. The $result_nbr variable tells mecha which one of the results it should follow next.

If we have several result pages we would also use the same trick to traverse through the result pages. For the **semantic extraction** of the entry information,we could parse the content of the actual entries with XML:LibXML's html parser (which works fine on this page), because it gives you some powerful DOM selection (using XPath) methods.
Well the actual looping through the pages should be doable in a few lines of perl of max. 20 lines - likely less.

**But wait**: the processing of the entry pages will then be the most complex part 
of the script.

**Approaches**: In principle we could do the same algorithm with a single while loop
if we use the back() function smartly.

Can you give me a hint for the beginning - the processing of the entry pages - doing  this in Perl:: Mechanize

Answer (score 0):

"Which has a dataset of 2700 foundations. All the data are free to use with no limitations copyrights on it."

Not true. See http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=905767

"The data is copyrighted even though it is made available freely: "Downloading or copying of texts, illustrations, photos or any other data does not entail any transfer of rights on the content." (and again, in German, as you've been scraping some other German list to spam before)."